# Font not found error fontspec using WinEdt in Windows

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, windows, winedt

I'm trying to compile a document and (as usual) I'm getting stuck with the `fontspec` package.   These are the only lines of code that I are giving me grief.

```
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newfontfamily\bodyfont[]{TeXGyreHerosCondensed}
\newfontfamily\thinfont[]{TexGyreHeros}
\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{TeXGyreHeros}
```

I've tried all sorts of ways to call `texgyreheros` including with spaces and by file name (in `C:\Windows\Fonts`). For some reason the system fonts aren't seeming to "link" with the LaTeX compiler.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Why `\RequirePackage`? Is this within your `.sty `file?

Comment: sorry, I was unclear. It's actually in a cls file that I'm using as a template for my document.

Comment: Are you using XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX? Can you tell us more about the class file you're using?

Comment: I'm sorry, I really should have said earlier. I'm using XeLatex

Comment: The class file I'm using is a modified friggeri-cv.cls available here: http://www.latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv.

Comment: The middle name is wrong: The x in Tex is lowercase instead of a versal. Beside this the names should work. But perhaps you need to run fc-cache to update the database.

Comment: How is this question different from the one you asked at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/150703/xelatex-with-fontspec-not-recognizing-any-fonts-on-a-windows-platform-with-mikt? You should edit your question here rather than starting a new one.