# XeLaTeX with fontspec not recognizing ANY fonts on a windows platform (with miktex)

Tags: fonts, xetex, fontspec, friggeri-cv

Getting the message: font-not-found see fontspec documentation. I'm using cls file abbreviated at the bottom of this page whose origin is latextemplates.com/template/friggeri-resume-cv. I've tried all sorts of fonts from system fonts and tex fonts. Nothing seems to work! I would like to get fonts like in http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/ to work, but I would be happy if I can just get one font to work!

```
\ProvidesClass{friggeri-cv}[2012/04/30 CV class]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\DeclareOption{print}{\def\@cv@print{}}
\DeclareOption*{%
\PassOptionsToClass{\CurrentOption}{article}%
}
\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}


%%%%%%%%%%
% Colors %
%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}
...

%%%%%%%%%
% Fonts %
%%%%%%%%%
\RequirePackage{fontspec}
\RequirePackage[math-style=TeX,vargreek-shape=unicode]{unicode-math}
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}

\RequirePackage{libertine}

\newfontfamily\bodyfont[]{\rm}
\newfontfamily\thinfont[]{\biolinum}
\newfontfamily\headingfont[]{\sc}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor]{Tex Gyre Heros}

%\setmathfont{XITS Math}

%%%%%%%%%%
% Header %
%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\rolefont}{%
  \fontsize{14pt}{24pt}\selectfont%
  \thinfont%
  \color{white}%
}

\newcommand{\header}[3]{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node [rectangle, fill=fillheader, anchor=north, minimum width=\paperwidth, minimum    height=4cm] (box) at (current page.north){};
    \node [anchor=center] (name) at (box) {%
      \fontsize{40pt}{72pt}\color{header}%
      {\thinfont #1}{\bodyfont  #2}
    };
\node [anchor=north] at (name.south) {%
  \fontsize{14pt}{24pt}\color{header}%
  \thinfont #3%
    };
  \end{tikzpicture}
  \vspace{2.5cm}
  \vspace{-2\parskip}
}

...
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 % Other tweaks %
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\RequirePackage[left=6.1cm,top=2cm,right=1.5cm,bottom=2.5cm,nohead,nofoot]{geometry}
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
```

Comment: Without an MWE -- minimum working example; a compilable document that (i) starts with `\documentclass` and ends with `\end{document}` and (ii) generates the problem behavior you're looking to fix -- it's not going to be likely that anyone will be able to offer a diagnosis, let alone a solution.

Comment: Don't test such things with complicated templates. Start with a small document which loads only fontspec and calls `\setmainfont{Arial}`. The line with `\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}` is wrong in your template. Delete it or move it before fontspec.

Comment: Without more information this one will be a miracle forever. I vote to close as unclear.